# Why was this closed and not the other?

Tags: discussion, closing

Why was this closed:

[https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6293/...](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6293/which-games-will-run-on-an-intel-atom-based-system-closed)

And this one was not:

[https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1932...](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/good-gaming-machine-for-starcraft-ii)

One asks for a list of games to run on a system and the other asks for what do you think is a good system to run a game.  Both appear to be of the list/opinion variety in a similar domain.  If one is then the other should be, yes?

Comment: This system, unfortunately, is operated by fallible humans. This is a beta. Expect things to be rough and make your votes count.

Comment: I'd like to see some consistency.

Comment: @Corv1nus consistency would be nice, as would consensus.  Unfortunately, our site lacks both, as witnessed in the [game-rec] and [fps] tag questions

Comment: Yes, consistency would be nice.

Comment: @Corv1nus I might point out you have the power to edit and vote to close...

Comment: @tzenes which I did vote for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, both questions are closed now! And since even with the presence of this question there are no reopen votes, I'm not seeing any interest in getting either open.

Nothing left to see here, let's all move along.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with this sort of logic "A isn't closed so B shouldn't be," is that it assumes there is a reason A isn't closed.  It suffers from the assumption that A has been left open on purpose and not because of neglect.

That said, the former question asks for people to decide what "runs well" means, where as the latter is requesting the required system specs.

Now I can see how you would think that these two are related based on the phrasing and the presence of "Bad Answers™" in the latter question (even my own answer is terrible).  In fact, the only right answer to the latter question is Kevin Y's which lists the manufacturers specifications.  All other answers are little more that supposition.

In effect, there is only one correct answer to the latter question (not a list of possible answers), where as the former would be a list of games (possibly infinite in length).

You have to realize the reason the Starcraft question was never cleaned up (and probably would get closed today) is that it was asked before the community really understood this difference.  Its largely been left alone because of neglect.

Comment: There may be one true "correct" answer but, when you ask what do you feel is the best it is crossing the line to opinion.  It becomes tell me what you think is the best machine to run this game on high.

Comment: @Corv1nus like I said the question is poorly phrased, and has not been cleaned up because of neglect not design

Comment: Also the assumption that A isn't closed because it was neglected came from the fact that it was answered 21 hours ago and on the front page.  They were practically beside each other for me for a brief period. That's neither here nor there though now at this point. It is what it is.

Comment: @Corv1nus it was asked Jul 15 at 3:20.  It was commented on recently which is why it got bumped.  Now that maybe an argument for locking or closing it, but is not a sign that it isn't largely neglected.